# Как присвоить переменной CLOB большой текст?

Tags: sql, строки, oracle, plsql

Есть переменная `csv_text`:

```
DECLARE
  csv_text        CLOB;
```

А как в нее добавить большой текст?

Т.к. если добавлять напрямую:

```
csv_text        := '*** Здесь текст длиной более 32767 символов ***';
```

Выдает ошибку:

> [65000][6550] ORA-06550: Строка 328, столбец 1:
>   PLS-00172: строковый литерал слишком длинный

Comment: Если вы используете не SQLPlus и надо разово записать данные в таблицу, то IDE обычно это умеют. Просто немного странно присваивать такой длинный текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Это означает что вы пытаетесь строковой переменной присвоить больше, чем 32767 символов, так как значение справа это не CLOB, a varchar2(32767)</s>.

Это означает что вы пытаетесь строковому литералу присвоить больше чем 32767 символов.

Чтобы это обойти разбейте свою строку на несколько. Вот пример.

```
DECLARE
  vStr1 VARCHAR2(32000);
  vStr2 VARCHAR2(32000);
  vClob CLOB;
BEGIN
  vStr1 := RPAD('*', 32000, '*');
  vStr2 := RPAD('*', 32000, '*');
  vClob := vStr1 || vStr2;

  dbms_output.put_line(length(vClob));
end;
```

Для ускорения работы, чтобы было меньше преобразований типов можно использовать `dbms_lob`.

```
DECLARE
  vStr1 VARCHAR2(32000);
  vStr2 VARCHAR2(32000);
  vClob CLOB;
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(vClob, true);

  vStr1 := RPAD('*', 32000, '*');
  vStr2 := RPAD('*', 32000, '*');

  dbms_lob.append(vClob, vStr1);
  dbms_lob.append(vClob, vStr2);

  dbms_output.put_line(length(vClob));

  dbms_lob.freetemporary(vClob);
end;
```

Comment: Первое предложение полностью неверно. _пытаетесь строковой переменной присвоить_, нет, ошибка раньше при объявлении литерала, т.е. до присвоения его значения переменной, поэтому ошибка собственно при компиляции, а не при выполнении. _a varchar2(32767)_, текстовый литерал это не varchar2, у него нет типа данных, это собственно текстовый литерал. 

Самый правильный ответ на вопрос в целом вы дали в комментарии - трудно найти практическое применение таким длинным текстовым литералам.

Comment: Так уже лучше +

Comment: Не совсем согласен ,что у строковых литералов нет типа, они тоже должны где-то храниться и сообщение ошибки *The string literal was longer than 32767 bytes* намекает, что внутри что-то очень похожее на *varchar2*. Но в целом все верно.

Comment: @0xdb спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: Литерал это же не переменная, как их БД внутри себя хранит, это её внутреннее дело. В [доку](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA), например: _Text literals have properties of both the CHAR and VARCHAR2 data types_, но нигде не сказано, какого конкретно. Литералы преобразуются при присвании в нужный тип, но до того, они просто литералы.